# Make my DBCluster DependOn serverless vpc plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless, amazon-vpc, amazon-aurora

I want to create a VPC with a DBCluster in it using the serverless-vpc-plugin. If I do it in two steps, first the VPC, and then the cluster, everything works. But if I do it simutaneously serverless fails, complaining that the DBSubnetGroup has not been created yet.

I tried makind the DBCluster `DependsOn: VPC` but nothing. Here are the relevant parts:

```
service: vpn
frameworkVersion: '2'

custom:
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  region: ${opt:region, self:provider.region}
  vpcConfig:
    createNatGateway: 1
    createNetworkAcl: true
    subnetGroups:
      - rds

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221

resources:
  Resources:
    ClusterSecret:
      Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
      Properties:
[...]

    AuroraDBCluster:
      Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
      DependsOn: VPC
      Properties:
        DatabaseName: [...]
        DBClusterIdentifier: [...]
        DBSubnetGroupName: ${self:service}-${self:custom.stage}
        Engine: aurora-postgresql
        EngineMode: serverless
        EngineVersion: "10.14"
        MasterUsername: [...]
        MasterUserPassword: [...]

plugins:
  - serverless-vpc-plugin
  - serverless-offline
```

Answer (score 1):

`DependsOn: RDSSubnetGroup` instead of `DependsOn: VPC` did the job